# Integration order changed but answer is different. Why?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, functions, definite-integrals

I have integrated function $x$ over domain:

\begin{cases}0\leqslant y\leqslant 2\sqrt{x}\\0\leqslant x\leqslant 5\end{cases} $$\iff$$
\begin{cases}0\leqslant y\leqslant 2\sqrt{5}\\y\leqslant x\leqslant 5\end{cases}.

in two ways by changing the order of integration.

\begin{align}
A &= \int_0^5 \int_0^{2\sqrt x} (x)\ dy\ dx\\
  &= \int_0^5 (x)\  \Biggr|   y   \Biggr|_0^{2\sqrt x}  dx\\
  &= 2 \int_0^5 x^{3/2} dx\\
  &= 2 \Biggr|   \dfrac{x^{5/2}}{5/2}  \Biggr|_0^5\\
  &= \dfrac{4}{5} \times 5^{5/2}\\
  &= 4 \times 5^{3/2}\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
B &= \int_0^{2\sqrt{5}} \int_y^5 (x)\ dx\ dy\\
  &= \int_0^{2\sqrt{5}}   \Biggr|   \dfrac{x^{2}}{2}  \Biggr|_y^5   dy\\
  &= \int_0^{2\sqrt{5}}   \left(   \dfrac{25}{2}-\dfrac{y^2}{2} \right)   dy\\
  &= \int_0^{2\sqrt{5}}   \left(   \dfrac{25}{2} \right)   dy
    -\int_0^{2\sqrt{5}}   \left(   \dfrac{y^2}{2} \right)   dy\\
  &= \dfrac{5^2}{2} \times 2\sqrt{5} 
    -\dfrac{1}{2} \Biggr|   \dfrac{y^{3}}{3}  \Biggr|_0^{2\sqrt{5}}\\
  &= 5^{5/2} -\dfrac{1}{6} (2\sqrt{5})^3\\
  &= 5^{5/2} -\dfrac{1}{6} \times 8 \times 5^{3/2}\\
  &= 5 \times 5^{3/2} - \dfrac{4}{3} \times 5^{3/2}\\
  &= 5^{3/2}  \left(   5-\dfrac{4}{3}  \right)\\
  &= \dfrac{11}{3} \times 5^{3/2}
\end{align}

As can be seen, I am getting two (slightly) different results. **Why is this so? Am I anywhere wrong in my calculations?**

Comment: Solving a positive $x$ from $y\le 2\sqrt{x}$ comes to $x\ge y^2/4$. I don't have a clue of where that $y\le x\le 5$ came from. Did you not draw a picture of the domain of integration? If you don't do that as the first thing, disasters are bound to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your regions are different. To see this, make a sketch of each region. The first region is bounded by the $x$-axis, the curve $y=2\sqrt{x}$ and the line $x=5$. The second region is a triangle bounded by the $x$-axis, and the lines $x=5$ and $y=x$.

When you change the order of integration, you should get $\frac{y^2}{4}\leq x\leq 5, 0\leq y\leq2\sqrt{5}$. The lower bound for $x$ comes from rearranging $y=2\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: The first region is what I am working with. Can you correct my second region and show it in the answer?

Comment: Now you're asking a different question. Why don't *you* draw the regions, try to describe the second one, and show us where you got stuck? That way you'll learn something.

Answer (score 1):

The lower domain is a triangle.

The upper domain has a curved edge (curved in a graph-of-sqrt shape).

So the integrals are different because the domains are different.